# How to use PropertyChangeSupport and PropertyChangeListener?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/scrape")
public class ScrapeController {
    private final PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        this.pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        this.pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    @GetMapping({"/", ""})
    public String scrape(){

        this.pcs.firePropertyChange("value", "wait", "scrape"); // Breakpoint.
        return "done";
    }
}


public class ScrapeService implements PropertyChangeListener {

    private final ScrapeController sc;

    public ScrapeService(ScrapeController sc) {
        this.sc = sc;
        sc.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("Name      = " + evt.getPropertyName()); // Breakpoint.
        System.out.println("Old Value = " + evt.getOldValue());
        System.out.println("New Value = " + evt.getNewValue());
    }
}
```

This project is based on Spring. But I don't believe that the problem is Spring related.

There are two breakpoints here.  The debugger stops at the first breakpoint in the `scrape` method where I fire the property change. But the debugger fails to stop at the breakpoint in the `propertyChange` method.  So the debug messages are not being printed.

Comment: When you have a moment, could you please clarify the problem.  Are you saying that your IDE doesn't stop at the breakpoint?  Or are you saying that the breakpoint inside your listener is never triggered?

Comment: @hooknc , IDE works perfectly. The problem is definitely with my code. What I mean is that I have failed to notify the listener of the event.

Comment: Understood, thank you for the clarification.  I see a couple of things that could be causing the problem.  First is that the `ScrapeService` object might never be created.  If the `ScrapeService` is being created, then you might have two different instances of the `ScrapeController`.  One that handles the actual http request and one that doesn't.  You can see if you have two different instances by looking at the object's hex memory value.

Comment: @hooknc , Thank you. ScrapeService really has never been created. I marked it with Service and it now works perfectly. If you organize this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. In other words, the solution is: (AT)Service
public class ScrapeService implements PropertyChangeListener {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the `ScrapeService` is never actually instantiated and added to the `ScrapeController`'s `addPropertyChangeListener` method.